# bringSubviewToFront problem?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

HI,
 I have Parentview-->Multiple childviews.
when i use [self  bringSubviewToFront:childview] in parentview, it works fine.but after adding grandchildview to childview,when i use 
[self  bringSubviewToFront: grandchildview] in parentview, it did not work?any help please?

Answer (score 64):

The `-[UIView bringSubviewToFront:]` method only works for direct children, not grandchildren. Remember that the view hierarchy is a tree, and normally a view only knows about its "parent" (or superview) and its direct "children" (or subviews). You would need to do something like this:

```
// First, get the view embedding the grandchildview to front.
[self bringSubviewToFront:[grandchildview superview]];
// Now, inside that container view, get the "grandchildview" to front. 
[[grandchildview superview] bringSubviewToFront:grandchildview];
```

Comment: doing this recursively would be even better

Comment: @PizzaiolaGorgonzola For arbitrary nesting levels, yes, a recursive method would be the way to go. For this simple case it would be overkill, though.

Comment: Thank you, I had been struggling with this issue for a while.

Comment: Fantastic code - really clean and works! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

my contribution with the swift version from the checked solution

```
self.bringSubviewToFront(self.grandchildview.superview!)
self.grandchildview.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(self.grandchildview)
```