# put some button button behind other

Tags: iphone, button, show, behind

Hi I'm making an app. with some (in part) overlapping buttons, & I want that when I push one of them, it comes up above every other buttons to show itself, but not hiding the others... sorry ab my english, i can't explain it better...
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-[UIView bringSubviewToFront:]`

More info: [bringSubviewToFront problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766778/bringsubviewtofront-problem)